# How to hide the status bar when presenting a UIAlertController in a non-UIViewController class?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am trying to hide the status bar when the user taps a button in a non-UIViewController class, but having no success.

I am using the following code to present the `UIAlertController`:

```
public extension UIAlertController
{
    func show()
    {
        let win = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let vc = UIViewController()
        vc.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        win.rootViewController = vc
        win.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1
        win.makeKeyAndVisible()    
        vc.present(self, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

It was referenced from the following answer by **jazzgil**:

[ios - present UIAlertController on top of everything regardless of the view hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42580981/2373410)

In my `UIButton` action I implemented the following:

```
@IBAction func setImage(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem)
{
    let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

    // Create the alert's action button
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in



    })

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "CANCEL", style: .destructive, handler: nil)

    alertView.addAction(okAction)
    alertView.addAction(cancelAction)

    alertView.show()
}
```

I have tried to add the following function within the extension:

```
override open var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool
{
    return true
}
```

Then set `alertView.modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance = true` as well as `alertView.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` but the status bar always seems to appear.

Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this help you.

To hide status bar call this method(in your case before presenting alertview controller)

```
func hideStatusBar() {
     UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar
}
```

And to get back status bar call this method(after dismissing alertview controller)

```
func updateStatusBarToPreviousState() {
     UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelNormal
 }
```

Comment: please explain answer and how to use

Comment: Simply you have to call method `hideStatusBar` to hide status bar and to show back call method `updateStatusBarToPreviousState` after dismissing alertview controller.

Comment: `hideStatusBar` works but when I call `updateStatusBarToPreviousState` in my okAction, the status bar never re-appears??