# Presenting Alert Controller from the delegate

Tags: ios, swift

In context of this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40991450/ios-present-uialertcontroller-on-top-of-everything-regardless-of-the-view-hier/42580981#42580981) I've attempted but the result is no alert presented.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    
    
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "ABc", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
    
    let win = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let vc = UIViewController()
    vc.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    win.rootViewController = vc
    win.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level.alert + 1  // Swift 3-4: UIWindowLevelAlert + 1
    win.makeKeyAndVisible()
    vc.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    return true
}
```

---

Attempt 2 based on the answer.

[image]

Comment: I don't see why `UIWindow` needs to get involved.

Comment: Why are you trying to present an alert in AppDelegate?!

Comment: I'm running some pre-startup related stuff before the app loads, I need to present an alert message in case any issues appear. Any solution?

Comment: The solution is to present it in the first view controller after it loads.

Comment: @cora code snippet please, I tried the answer below but `self.window` is nil to begin with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use below line:**

`self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

**Instead of**

`vc.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

than problem is solved.

**Example:**

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.5, execute: {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert Title", message:
          "Message", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style:.default) {
            UIAlertAction in
            NSLog("OK Pressed")
        }

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) {
            UIAlertAction in
            NSLog("Cancel Pressed")
        }

        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
```

Comment: `self.window` is nil within `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

Comment: Hello, can you please try your answer and post a working example?

Comment: @AppDeveloper please see my updated answer

Comment: No its not working, https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5raz.png, you have a compilation error as well, please test the code.

Comment: sorry to say, nops, https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpnGV.png increased delay as well, I'm using navigation controller as initial view contorller in my app, is that the difference? Can you please post a screenshot from your end?

Comment: ok will upload if yo're using a navigationController.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225767/discussion-between-virani-vivek-and-appdeveloper).